# TeamCity doesn't fetch tags

Tags: git, teamcity

I'm building GitHub pull requests in TeamCity. I'm setting the branch specification in git VCS root to `+:refs/(pull/*)/head`. I'm checking out the sources on agent.

With such setup I see that TeamCity doesn't fetch tags - the .git/refs/tags folder is empty.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

There is a small checkbox in your vcs settings that says "use tags as branches" (exact wording might differ across versions). Please check that box.

Also, you want to checkout pull requests which is different from tags. Last i checked github did not have the facility where you can check out pull requests. Please double check that aspect

Comment: Pull requests work like charm. Here's a how-to from jetbrains: http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity/

Comment: And I don't see that checkbox. I'm using version 7.1.4. Any idea when it came about?

Comment: I am not sure for github, but I do not think pull requests are the same as tags